# Facebook post message on wall through Fb Application with graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, oauth

I'm facing a weird issue with Facebook, I'm currently developping an application with Phonegap.

I followed the really cool tutorial of this blog http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88 and improved it to be able to make it work with the new API and also to allow me to Post message.

So I'm using oAuth to connect with Facebook and everything works fine. Then I have been able to post message through graph api with the same Token.

So I have this method who works perfectly, when I'm using my Facebook account (I am the administrator of the Facebook application)

```
share:function(url, success){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', url, true);
    var _interval = setTimeout(function(){
        success.call(this, false);
    }, 31000);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200){clearTimeout(_interval); success.call(this, true);}}
    req.send(null);
    return req;
},

post:function(_fbType,params, success){
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/'+_fbType+'?'+localStorage.getItem(facebook_token);

    for(var key in params){
        if(key == "message"){
            url = url+"&"+key+"="+escape(params[key]);
        }
        else {
            url = url+"&"+key+"="+encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
        }
    }
    var req = Facebook.share(url, success);
},
```

But if it's not an administrator of the application who use my application, the connexion will works fine but if try to post wit won't work.

On my Facebook application the Sandbox mode is disabled. The app center review haven't been made yet, maybe the problem come from this ?

Comment: try changing "me" with current Facebook User ID ?!

Comment: Hello Shpat,Thank you for your answer, I tried. it still working the same with my account but not with someone else it's not.

Comment: do you have acess_token in your parameters ??

Comment: Yeah I have access_token=xxxx in my parameters or something like that, I'm just consider the bug could from Facebook Application parameters but I have no clue about it, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this FaceBook [Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/). `method: 'feed'` **feed** is the keyword for wallpost. this is not only for gaming. we can use for app and all.

Comment: Thank you Karsho, I'm currently using 'feed' and it's working successfully with my admin fb application account but not with normal user account.